# rdesktop failing with BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)

Tags: linux, xmonad, rdesktop

```sh
$ rdesktop localhost -u username
Autoselecting keyboard map 'en-us' from locale
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  20 (X_GetProperty)
  Resource id in failed request:  0xc00001
  Serial number of failed request:  42
  Current serial number in output stream:  42
```

Version is 1.9.0.

Passing a different hostname, even a non-existent one doesn't change anything.

It used to work before, so I suspect some recent upgrade of the system introduced this problem.

I'm using xmonad.org window manager, which might also contribute to some less standard GUI environment.

Comment: (1) Try running `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-swx11`. (2) Try another [FreeRDP client](https://github.com/FreeRDP).

Comment: I'm using a customized repo that doesn't provide `libgl1-mesa-swx11`. However using `xfreerdp` indeed works, thanks!

Still I'd be curious to know if it's possible to fix `rdesktop`. I already had had installed `libgl1-mesa-dri`, `libgl1-mesa-glx` and `libglx-mesa0` when I experienced the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xfreerdp` is a newer fork of `rdesktop` and it worked better for the
poster than `rdesktop`.

According to [FreeRDP on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeRDP) :

> FreeRDP was forked in 2009 from rdesktop with the aim of modularizing the code, addressing various issues, and implementing new features.

Unfortunately Wikipedia's list of features do not list which are the
same as `rdesktop` and which are new.

The FreeRDP [1.0 release announcement](http://www.freerdp.com/2012/01/16/freerdp-1-0-released/) (Jan 2012) did offer this list of new features, which presumably are not also available on `rdesktop`:

> - RemoteFX
>
>   - Both encoder and decoder
>   - SSE2 and NEON optimization
> - NSCodec
> - RemoteApp
>
>   - Working, minor glitches
> - Multimedia Redirection
>
>   - ffmpeg support
> - Network Level Authentication (NLA)
>
>   - NTLMv2
> - Certificate validation
> - FIPS-compliant RDP security
> - new build system (cmake)
> - added official logo and icon

I assume that one of these newer features (or one not listed)
is responsible for `xfreerdp` working, while the older `rdesktop`
did not work.

Source :
[What are the differences between rdesktop and xfreerdp?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140047/what-are-the-differences-between-rdesktop-and-xfreerdp/188168#188168)